# Mongoose вложенный обьект в схеме

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Доброго дня уважаемые колеги. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не работает такой вариант вложенности в схеме мунгуса и как правильно сделать его ?

```
mongoose.schema('media', {
                name : String,
                sourceName : String,
                altText : String,
                detail : {album : String, category : String, type : String},
                date : Date
            });

var model = mongoose.model('Media', media);

mediaModel = new Media_Module.mediaModelScheme({
                        name : 'test',
                        sourceName : 'test1',
                        altText : 'test2',
                        detail : {album : 'test3'
                            ,category : 'test4'
                            ,type : 'test5'},
                        date : Date.now()
                    });
```

При сохранении документа получаю такую ошибку: Cast to String failed for value "[object Object]" at path "detail"

Знаю что можно делать так, но хотелось бы напрямую писать вложенный обьект:

```
 /* nested scheme */
        this.mediaDetailScheme = this.db.getScheme('detail', {
            album : String,
            category: String,
            type : String
        });


            /* primary scheme */
        this.mediaModelScheme = this.db.getModel('media', {
                name : String,
                sourceName : String,
                altText : String,
                detail : [this.mediaDetailScheme],
                date : Date
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Причина:** `type` - зарезервированное слово для mongoose.

`detail: {type: String}` равносильно `detail: String`

**Решение:** Используйте `mytype`, `_type` и прочие ключи.

**Ссылки:** http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html (en)